# Tensorflow giving Unknow Dtype Policy

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I Am trying to train a model  in Colab and then transferring it to Kaggle. The Model seems to Work fine in Colab as a .h5 model. The problem seems to be with Efficient net B4 and after in Kaggle. There is No Documentation about This. I am training this model on a TPU and doing the inference on a GPU but even if i train the model on GPU this problem is There.

My error Log

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-2ca8d6accabd> in <module>
     10 policy = mixed_precision.Policy('mixed_bfloat16')
     11 mixed_precision.set_policy(policy)
---> 12 model = tf.keras.models.load_model(r"../input/model-for-training/effieceintnettpurandomcrop.h5")
     13 
     14 model.summary()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    182     if (h5py is not None and (
    183         isinstance(filepath, h5py.File) or h5py.is_hdf5(filepath))):
--> 184       return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    185 
    186     if sys.version_info >= (3, 4) and isinstance(filepath, pathlib.Path):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py in load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    176     model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
    177     model = model_config_lib.model_from_config(model_config,
--> 178                                                custom_objects=custom_objects)
    179 
    180     # set weights

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/model_config.py in model_from_config(config, custom_objects)
     53                     '`Sequential.from_config(config)`?')
     54   from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import deserialize  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
---> 55   return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
     56 
     57 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
    107       module_objects=globs,
    108       custom_objects=custom_objects,
--> 109       printable_module_name='layer')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    371             custom_objects=dict(
    372                 list(_GLOBAL_CUSTOM_OBJECTS.items()) +
--> 373                 list(custom_objects.items())))
    374       with CustomObjectScope(custom_objects):
    375         return cls.from_config(cls_config)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py in from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)
    396     for layer_config in layer_configs:
    397       layer = layer_module.deserialize(layer_config,
--> 398                                        custom_objects=custom_objects)
    399       model.add(layer)
    400     if (not model.inputs and build_input_shape and

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
    107       module_objects=globs,
    108       custom_objects=custom_objects,
--> 109       printable_module_name='layer')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    373                 list(custom_objects.items())))
    374       with CustomObjectScope(custom_objects):
--> 375         return cls.from_config(cls_config)
    376     else:
    377       # Then `cls` may be a function returning a class.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in from_config(cls, config)
    653         A layer instance.
    654     """
--> 655     return cls(**config)
    656 
    657   def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/normalization.py in __init__(self, axis, momentum, epsilon, center, scale, beta_initializer, gamma_initializer, moving_mean_initializer, moving_variance_initializer, beta_regularizer, gamma_regularizer, beta_constraint, gamma_constraint, renorm, renorm_clipping, renorm_momentum, fused, trainable, virtual_batch_size, adjustment, name, **kwargs)
    198                **kwargs):
    199     super(BatchNormalizationBase, self).__init__(
--> 200         name=name, **kwargs)
    201     if isinstance(axis, (list, tuple)):
    202       self.axis = axis[:]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    454     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    455     try:
--> 456       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    457     finally:
    458       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __init__(self, trainable, name, dtype, dynamic, **kwargs)
    336     # fields, like the loss scale, are used by Models. For subclassed networks,
    337     # the compute and variable dtypes are used as like any ordinary layer.
--> 338     self._set_dtype_policy(dtype)
    339     # Boolean indicating whether the layer automatically casts its inputs to the
    340     # layer's compute_dtype.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _set_dtype_policy(self, dtype)
   1986       self._dtype_policy = dtype
   1987     elif isinstance(dtype, dict):
-> 1988       self._dtype_policy = policy.deserialize(dtype)
   1989     elif dtype:
   1990       self._dtype_policy = policy.Policy(dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).name)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/mixed_precision/experimental/policy.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
    628       module_objects=module_objects,
    629       custom_objects=custom_objects,
--> 630       printable_module_name='dtype policy')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    360     config = identifier
    361     (cls, cls_config) = class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object(
--> 362         config, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    363 
    364     if hasattr(cls, 'from_config'):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object(config, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    319   cls = get_registered_object(class_name, custom_objects, module_objects)
    320   if cls is None:
--> 321     raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ': ' + class_name)
    322 
    323   cls_config = config['config']

ValueError: Unknown dtype policy: PolicyV1
```

My model Training Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.mixed_precision import experimental as mixed_precision
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l1

policy = mixed_precision.Policy('mixed_bfloat16')
mixed_precision.set_policy(policy)
reg = l1(0.001)

with strategy.scope():
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB3(weights="imagenet", include_top=False)
    base_model.trainable = True

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        base_model,
        BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
        tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(256),
        BatchNormalization(),

        tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
        BatchNormalization(),

        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128),
        BatchNormalization(),

        tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
        BatchNormalization(),

        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
        BatchNormalization(),

        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64),
        BatchNormalization(),

        tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(32),
        BatchNormalization(),

        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),

        tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(16),

        tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(8),
        tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(CLASSES), activation='softmax')
    ])

    model.compile(
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.04),
        loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping

early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                      mode='min',
                      patience=5)
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 17118 // BATCH_SIZE
VALID_STEPS = 4279 // BATCH_SIZE
checkpoint_filepath = 'gs://mithil/tmp/checkpoint_temp'
model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor='val_sparse_categorical_accuracy',
    mode='max',
    save_best_only=True)

history = model.fit(train_dataset,
                    steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,

                    epochs=25,
                    validation_data=valid_dataset,
                    validation_steps=VALID_STEPS, callbacks=[early,model_checkpoint_callback])
model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)
```

Inference Code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import cv2
from collections import Counter
from tensorflow.keras.mixed_precision import experimental as mixed_precision

from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l1
policy = mixed_precision.Policy('mixed_bfloat16')
mixed_precision.set_policy(policy)
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(r"../input/model-for-training/effieceintnettpurandomcrop.h5")

model.summary()
path = "../input/cassava-leaf-disease-classification/test_images"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem when I saved the model with tf-version 2.4 and loaded it with tf-version 2.3. Fixed it by upgrading to 2.4.

Maybe helpful to someone who stumbles upon this question from google.

Answer (score 0):

What gebbissimo states is true.

If you insist using tensorflow 2.3 what you can do is recreate the model in tensorflow 2.3 in code.
Then you can load the weights by model.load_weights() with the same h5 file.

You can use the model then for inference. If you do not want to recreate the model everytime you can model.save_model() after loading weights in tf 2.3.

The saved model will be compatible with tensorflow 2.3 and tensorflow 2.4.